# Mysterious ARM Opcode

Tags: arm, disassembly, cortex-m, opcode, thumb

In decompiling a hex file for a Texas Instruments ARM (Thumb 2) Cortex-M4f processor (CC2652RB), I have come across an opcode that I can't figure out.
What does "90 FF FF 00" do (maybe the context below helps)?  Is Texas Instruments allowed to use custom opcodes if they aren't claimed in the ARM standard?

```
19 46          mov     r1, r3
06 4A          ldr     r2, [pc, #0x18]
00 28          cmp     r0, #0
11 60          str     r1, [r2]
18 BF          it      ne
01 20          movne   r0, #1
BC BD          pop     {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, pc}
90 FF FF 00    ?
14 20          movs    r0, #0x14
02 40          ands    r2, r0
04 04          lsls    r4, r0, #0x10
00 20          movs    r0, #0
30 72          strb    r0, [r6, #8]
05 00          movs    r5, r0
08 04          lsls    r0, r1, #0x10
00 20          movs    r0, #0
F0 B5          push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
40 F6 FF 7C    movw    ip, #0xfff
10 F8 01 3B    ldrb    r3, [r0], #1
00 24          movs    r4, #0
08 2C          cmp     r4, #8
```

EDIT: Here is more of what precedes this mysterious line (with an arbitrary address start) since Nate Eldredge pointed out that this line probably starts literal data used by the preceding function:

```
0x40:  18 B1          cbz    r0, #    0x4a
0x42:  00 F0 1F FA    bl     #    0x484
0x46:  00 20          movs   r0, #0
0x48:  BC BD          pop    {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, pc}
0x4a:  00 F0 07 F8    bl     #    0x5c
0x4e:  BC BD          pop    {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, pc}
0x50:  00 09          lsrs   r0, r0, #4
0x52:  3D 00          movs   r5, r7
0x54:  B4 01          lsls   r4, r6, #6
0x56:  00 10          asrs   r0, r0, #    0x20
0x58:  14 20          movs   r0, #    0x14
0x5a:  02 40          ands   r2, r0
0x5c:  BC B5          push   {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, lr}
0x5e:  16 48          ldr    r0, [pc, #    0x58]
0x60:  16 4D          ldr    r5, [pc, #    0x58]
0x62:  04 21          movs   r1, #4
0x64:  01 90          str    r0, [sp, #4]
0x66:  00 20          movs   r0, #0
0x68:  28 70          strb   r0, [r5]
0x6a:  01 A8          add    r0, sp, #4
0x6c:  00 F0 8A FA    bl     #    0x584
0x70:  10 B1          cbz    r0, #    0x78
0x72:  01 20          movs   r0, #1
0x74:  28 70          strb   r0, [r5]
0x76:  07 E0          b      #    0x88
0x78:  11 4C          ldr    r4, [pc, #    0x44]
0x7a:  02 21          movs   r1, #2
0x7c:  20 46          mov    r0, r4
0x7e:  00 F0 AF F9    bl     #    0x3e0
0x82:  01 21          movs   r1, #1
0x84:  29 70          strb   r1, [r5]
0x86:  08 B1          cbz    r0, #    0x8c
0x88:  00 20          movs   r0, #0
0x8a:  BC BD          pop    {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, pc}
0x8c:  0D 4B          ldr    r3, [pc, #    0x34]
0x8e:  22 78          ldrb   r2, [r4]
0x90:  64 78          ldrb   r4, [r4, #1]
0x92:  03 F1 20 01    add.w  r1, r3, #    0x20
0x96:  18 68          ldr    r0, [r3]
0x98:  40 B1          cbz    r0, #    0xac
0x9a:  1D 79          ldrb   r5, [r3, #4]
0x9c:  AA 42          cmp    r2, r5
0x9e:  02 D1          bne    #    0xa6
0xa0:  5D 79          ldrb   r5, [r3, #5]
0xa2:  AC 42          cmp    r4, r5
0xa4:  01 D0          beq    #    0xaa
0xa6:  08 33          adds   r3, #8
0xa8:  F5 E7          b      #    0x96
0xaa:  19 46          mov    r1, r3
0xac:  06 4A          ldr    r2, [pc, #    0x18]
0xae:  00 28          cmp    r0, #0
0xb0:  11 60          str    r1, [r2]
0xb2:  18 BF          it     ne
0xb4:  01 20          movne  r0, #1
0xb6:  BC BD          pop    {r2, r3, r4, r5, r7, pc}
```

Comment: That opcode is in a range reserved for coprocessors.  I can't say what TI has done here for sure - but if they wanted to add custom opcodes, implementing them as a coprocessor would be the normal, expected way to do so.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks.  So, shouldn't TI specify what this operation does somewhere?  Hoping someone can at least tell me what document to look in...

Comment: Are you sure it is actually executed?  The immediately preceding instruction is an unconditional branch (`pop pc`), so the only way to reach the weird "instruction" would be to branch to it from somewhere else.  Is there any evidence of such a branch?  If not, then another possibility is that it's a literal pool, so that word may actually be data.  But something else is weird, because the `[pc, #0x18]` a few lines previously should also point to a literal pool, but it points to later code instead.  Did you omit some lines?  Can you post a disassembly that includes addresses?

Comment: Oh, actually I bet everything up to the next `push` is the literal pool.  It looks like sensible code at first glance, but it's actually not, because it computes a bunch of stuff that is never used.  And it doesn't make sense that it falls through the `push` into the next function (unless the author is [Mel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Mel)).  I bet it's just a coincidence that it disassembles as semi-meaningful intstructions.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, I didn't omit any lines and the addresses for the disassembled snippet are just sequential with no absolute importance (the #0x18 is not an absolute address, just a relative shift, so you can pick any starting address that you want and you still get #0x18 from the disassembler).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but having addresses would make it easier to see where `pc+0x18` is, without having to count bytes by hand.  It's the relative addresses that would help; I agree the absolute addresses are irrelevant.

Comment: disassemblers do the best they can.  This core has variable length instructions and that already causes problems with disassemblers.  Then if you are simply objdump -D or something then all the data gets disassembled too.   It is relatively easy to confuse them even further (x86 is a nightmare to disasseble and if you think your disassembler does a good job they have you fooled).  you can use labels and correlate this with the function in the high level language as well as have the compiler generate assembly language (never just do that, disassemble as well, esp for this platform)

Comment: as answered this is highly likely to just be data in the literal pool.  generic use of a disassembler is expected to have unknown instructions as well as get tripped up.  perfectly normal, the unkowns are either data or the tool got confused because it is operating linearly instead of in execution order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's not an instruction at all, but rather data.  The preceding instruction is a `pop {..., pc}` that would normally be the return at the end of  function.  So this "instruction" isn't reachable by straight line execution.  You could only execute it by a branch from somewhere else, and I bet you won't find one.

But after the end of a function is a natural place to find a literal pool.  In fact, I suspect everything from the mystery word up to the `push { ..., lr}` several lines further down (which would be the natural first instruction of the next function) is a literal pool.  Note for instance that the `ldr r2, [pc, #0x18]` above, which is most definitely a load from a literal pool, would also load from within this region.

The disassembly of the bytes following the mystery word looks at first glance like reasonable code, but on further inspection are questionable.  It would clobber registers that would normally be call-preserved (r4, r5), and further down there's `lsls r0, ...` whose result is immediately overwritten with `mov r0, #0`.

And as mentioned the fall-through into a more plausible function prologue would be strange.  In fact, it would then execute the `ldrb r3, [r0, #1]` with `r0 = 0` which would inevitably crash.

I suspect if you disassemble the rest of the preceding function, you will find somewhere a pc-relative load that loads the mystery word as data.

Comment: Ok.  You're most likely right, but I'm a bit new to assembly coding so I probably won't go searching for the pc-relative load to prove it.  For a little background, my disassembler also choked on "80 F3 08 88" and "EF F3 10 80" opcodes, which I concluded to both be "MRS.W" instructions (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) after much searching, so I thought the one in my question would also be some operation.  Alas, it's (probably) just a boring block of data, thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Someone else might be better at spotting where data gets used, so I just added more disassembly code to the question in an edit...maybe you can spot the mysterious line's reference right away!

Comment: Yes, it's the one at 0x5e.  pc is always the current instruction plus 4, and literal `ldr` rounds it down to a multiple of 4 before adding the displacement.  So on this instruction, we have pc = 0x62, rounded down to 0x60, plus 0x58 yields 0xb8 which is the address of your mystery word.  A nicer disassembler would do this arithmetic for you, and annotate the `ldr` with the actual target address.

Comment: @bobuhito: The other literal loads have target addresses that increase by 4 each time, as one would expect, and they total 20 bytes which takes us exactly to the `push` that presumably starts the next function.